# Golang alternative for python/flask send_from_directory()

Tags: go, go-gin

I have this image urls:

```
/book/cover/Computer_Science.png
```

but the location of the image actually exists under

```
/uploads/img/Computer_Science.png
```

I'm using **Gin framework**. Is there any command like Flask's `send_from_directory()` in Gin or in in-built Golang functions?

If not could you share a snippet of how to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use gin's [`Context.File`](https://godoc.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.File) to serve file content. This method internally calls [http.ServeFile](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeFile) builtin function. The code snippets will be:

```
import "path/filepath"


// ...
router := gin.Default()
// ... 

router.GET("/book/cover/:filename", func(c *gin.Context) {
    rootDir := "/uploads/img/"
    name := c.Param("filename")
    filePath, err :=  filepath.Abs(rootDir + name)
    if err != nil {
        c.AbortWithStatus(404)
    }

    //Only allow access to file/directory under rootDir
    //The following code is for ilustration since HasPrefix is deprecated.
    //Replace with correct one when https://github.com/golang/dep/issues/296 fixed
    if !filepath.HasPrefix(filePath, rootDir) {
        c.AbortWithStatus(404)
    }

    c.File(filePath)
})
```

**Update**

As pointed by zerkms, the path name **must be sanitized** before passing it `Context.File`. Simple sanitizer is added in the snippet. Please adapt to your needs.

Comment: I think it worth mentioning that one also need to check if the resulted normalized path is within the expected directory, otherwise one might request `/book/cover/../../../../../../../etc/passwd`

Comment: @zerkms Thank you, you're correct. I've updated the answer.